# not able to understand a dp solution

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem is as follows:

> Lazer Tag consists of a group play, where you are assigned a fixed number of bullets (popularly known as Laser shots) during the whole game. Each right shoot on your target enemy, gives you one point.
>
> Consider the series of your hits and misses which can be represented in the form of “x” and “o” where “o” represents a hit and “x” represents a miss. Suppose the series is of the form “xxxoooxxxxooxxo”, then your final score will be equal to `3^2 + 2^2 +1^2` i.e add up the squares of every maximal number of consecutive hits in the entire game play.
>
> The probability of hitting the jth shot correctly (1≤j≤n) is P(j). In simpler terms, the probability of getting an “o” in the series at jth turn is P(j). You need to calculate the expected score at the end of your round.

I can understand a O(n^2) solution of this using memoization but the question requires a O(n) solution. I have seen the O(n) solution but I am not able to understand it. The O(n) solution is as follows:

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    dp[i] = (dp[i-1] + p[i-1]) * p[i];   
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    ans+=2 * dp[i] + p[i];
```

where p[i] is the prob of hitting ith target. Can anyone explain how the O(n) solution works?

Comment: The solution you posted is not correct. That might be part of why you are having trouble understanding it. Just run a simulation of it, averaging your random results a few million times and you'll see it gives a different result.

Comment: @Chill the solution is correct. This is the problem link [http://www.codechef.com/TCFST13/problems/TCFST05/] and the solution i have given is one of the accepted ones

Comment: There must be something wrong with my simulation then. Check it out and let me know if you see any problems. http://pastebin.com/NHWgK1fZ

Comment: `“o” represents a hit and “x” represents a miss` WHY???

Comment: What does dp[0] contain at the start?

Comment: @j_random_hacker "o represents a hit and "x" represents a miss" thats just how the ques is framed,it has nothing much to do with the soln.dp[0] contains 0 at the start.

Comment: @user2094963: It wasn't a serious comment.  All I meant was that 99% of the time, "X" means "hit" and "O" means "miss".  It would be like if the question talked about a traffic light that used red to indicate "go" and green to indicate "stop" :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of the scoring in the following way:

1. 1 point for each hit
2. 2 points for EVERY run of hits of length >1 (scoring overlapping runs multiple times)

For example, a sequence of xxooox would score:

1. +1 for each of the o's
2. +2 for ooo
3. +2 for first oo
4. +2 for second oo

Score = 1*3+2*3 = 3+6 = 9 points.  (This matches the original way of score because 9=3*3)

dp[i] computes the expected number of runs of length >1 that end at position i.

So to compute the total expected score we need to sum 2*dp[i] (as we get 2 points for every run), plus the sum of p[i] to add the expected score from getting 1 point for each hit.

The recurrence relation is because the expected number of runs of length >1 ending at position i will be:

1. +1 if we have a new run starting at position i by getting a hit at i and i-1 (probability p[i]*p[i-1])
2. +dp[i-1] if we continue the runs ending at position i-1 by getting another hit (probability p[i])

Comment: could u explain how u came up with the scoring technique i.e 1 for each o, +2 for ooo .... .i am new to dp and wanted to know how to approach such ques

Comment: Very insightful Peter, I'd love to know how you noticed that!

Comment: I think this is more of a mathematical thing than a common DP technique.  (I think I might have seen something similar in some Project Euler problem once upon a time.)

Comment: @user2094963 the insight is much more about computing a quadratic function in a weird way that is amendable to a probabilistic recurrence.  it's definitely cool and clever solution to this particular problem, but you don't need to understand it to solve DP problems generally.

Comment: @rrenaud can this problem be solved in any other way in O(n) time?